# Algorithm to recursively parse XML nodes

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, xml-parsing

I have got the XML lib to parse text, but I am not getting a recursive algorithm to parse.
Can someone provide me a sample recursive algorithm to iterate all nodes in XML?

Comment: The problem with Xerces-C++ is...?

Comment: Is it a stream- or dom-oriented parser?

Answer (score 0):

For these purposes, is typically used visitor pattern:

> In object-oriented programming and software engineering, the visitor
>   design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object
>   structure on which it operates. A practical result of this separation
>   is the ability to add new operations to existing object structures
>   without modifying those structures. It is one way to easily follow the
>   open/closed principle. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)